# Fit a Mean forecasting model using tsibble, fable in R

Tags: r, time-series, tidyverse, tsibble

(Using Orange dataset from `library(Ecdat)` for reproducibility.)

I am trying to fit a mean forecasting model in R using tsibble, fable package in R. The code below is pretty simple, however I get the error `Error in NCOL(x) : object 'value' not found` when I try to run the last model part (even though `value` is a column name in `o_ts`), not sure why would that be. I am following RJH tutorials from here (https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/fable/).

I would also appreciate any help whether arima & mean forecasting model are same, if not what is the function that I should be using instead of Arima.

```
library(Ecdat)
library(tsibble)
library(feasts)
library(tidyverse)
library(fable)

o<- Orange 

o_ts <- o %>% as_tsibble()

o_ts %>%
  filter(key=="priceoj") %>% 
  model(
    arima=arima(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

`arima` is from the `stats` package. I believe you want `ARIMA` from `fable`.

```
o_ts %>%
  filter(key == "priceoj") %>% 
  model(
    arima = ARIMA(value)
  )
#> # A mable: 1 x 2
#> # Key:     key [1]
#>   key                         arima
#>   <chr>                     <model>
#> 1 priceoj <ARIMA(1,1,0)(0,0,1)[12]>
```

Comment: Thanks  thats correct, can you also confirm if its same as mean forecasting which is what I am confused with

Comment: Also, any idea why do I get a null model ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with definition of `mean forecast model`. I'm not sure why you're getting a null model - I don't get a null model when I run it. Perhaps try restarting R and running again?

Answer (score 1):

If you by mean forecasting model are referring to taking the [mean of the last X observation](https://otexts.com/fpp3/simple-methods.html) (Moving Average), then you should be using `MEAN`.
While `ARIMA` does refer to Moving Average (Auto Regressive Integrated Moving Average), however this refers to a weighted moving average of the forecast errors - you can read more here: [9.4 Moving average models in Forecasting: Principles and Practice](https://otexts.com/fpp3/MA.html)

```
o <- Orange 

o_ts <- o %>% as_tsibble()

o_ts %>%
  filter(key == "priceoj") %>% 
  model(mean = MEAN(value))
```

If you want to specify the amount of observations to take the mean of, then you need to add the special `~window(size = X)`. Otherwise all observations are used.

```
o_ts %>%
  filter(key == "priceoj") %>% 
  model(mean = MEAN(value ~ window(size = 3)))
```