# cannot pipe %>% tsibble filter past autoplot into autolayer

Tags: r, ggplot2, tsibble, autoplot

Using the code below and nycflight13 data as example, I am unable to pass filter to autolayer. First autoplot code works; second returns error object 'temp' not found. temp is not being passed into autolayer.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyselect)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggplotify)
library(broom)
library(forecast)
library(fpp3)
library(fable)
library(tsibble)
library(fabletools)
library(tidyr)

weather <- nycflights13::weather %>% 
  select(origin, time_hour, temp, humid, precip)
weather_tsbl <- as_tsibble(weather, key = origin, index = time_hour)

##this works
weather_tsbl %>%
  filter(origin == "EWR") %>%
  autoplot(temp)

##this code temp does not get piped into autolayer Error: obect 'temp' not found
weather_tsbl %>%
  filter(origin == "EWR") %>%
  autoplot(temp)+
    autolayer(meanf(temp, h=20), series="Mean", PI=FALSE)
```

Tried group_map( ... ) or setting everything in ( ).  Why doesn't it pass through? Also tried |> to pipe as well...
Eventually want to plot mean, niave, and drift layers of another tsibble I have which is encountering same issue... can't pass the filter into autolayer.

Comment: If you have it, can you share an example of code where the `autolayer` line is working? In general, that would help someone understand if it's an issue with that line or with its combination with the prior one.

Comment: Are you committed to an `autoplot`/`autolayer` approach?

Comment: Just like `autoplot()`, `autolayer()` requires a forecast to be provided to the first argument.  `meanf(temp, h = 20)` does not work in this case since `temp` cannot be found - it's within a column of the data.

Comment: @JonSpring Looking to make simple forecasts like in [Forecasting: Principles and Practice Section 3.1](https://otexts.com/fpp2/simple-methods.html)

Comment: fyi next edition available: https://otexts.com/fpp3/simple-methods.html

Comment: Yes, and this autolayer section is not in 3 ed. I was able to get it to work just calling in a ts. Piping in from a tsibble doesn't seem to work. I guess it's more the tsibble.
Thanks for input though.

Answer (score 1):

`autoplot()` is great for initial exploration, but I find it much easier to troubleshoot and make changes if I prepare the data and modeling first, then feed it into a ggplot I specify. For this, I incorporated some code from the [fable  vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fable/vignettes/fable.html), which shows examples of generating multiple models, and this [SO question re a sliding window mean model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64459298/fit-a-mean-forecasting-model-using-tsibble-fable-in-r).

```
weather_tsbl %>%
  filter(origin == "EWR") %>%
  model(mean = MEAN(temp),
        mean_window = MEAN(temp ~ window(size = 20))) %>%
  augment() %>%
  ggplot(aes(time_hour, temp)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(y = .fitted, color = .model))
```

[image]